# how to write a query to count the number of days that a user has logged in?

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

The site log records a datetime stamp each time a user logs in.  I am in need of a query to count the number of days that a user has logged in.  Just doing a count on the [DateTime] field doesn't work because a user can login more than once per day.  So, I am stumped as how to just count distinct days that they logged in.  Basically, we need the query to produce:

```
UserID
NumberOfDaysLoggedIn
```

For example, User John (ID 33) logins in as such:

```
3/26/2008 12:20 PM
3/26/2008 5:58 PM
3/27/2008 11:46 AM
```

The results we want would be:

```
UserID    NumberofDaysLoggedIn
    33                       2
```

Any ideas to produce that results by using oracle query . please suggest any idea

Answer (score 3):

what you should do is round the dates and then put them under distinct.

the function that round dates is `trunc()`.

you can do it like that:

```
select count(*)
from (select name, trunc(date)
      from table
      group by name, trunc(date))
where name = 'John';
```

if you want to get the result for each user you could do it like that:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select distinct name, trunc(date)
      from table)
group by name;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to do something like;

```
select userID, count(distinct trunc(date))
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count distinct dates, something along the lines of:

```
select count(distinct trunc(t.date))
  from table t
 where t.userId = some user id
```

`trunc()` truncates the date to the day value but can also take format parameter for truncating to a specific unit of measure.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as 
(
select 1 as id, sysdate as d from dual
union all
select 1 as id, sysdate - 0.5 as d from dual
union all
select 1 as id, sysdate - 0.6 as d from dual
union all
select 1 as id, sysdate - 1 as d from dual
union all
select 2 as id, sysdate - 1 as d from dual
)
select id, count(distinct trunc(d))
from t 
group by id
;
```